# How to use "FIND" as a first and last row to look value at, to match value and copy adjacent cell to another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, string, find, export

I am stuck with Type mismatch Error 13 on Find operator. As data on my workbooks are not placed in predictable place, I need to find "From:" first and look for "Serial No" as source numbers just before Finding "To:". After completing Source or From Serial Nos, I need to copy To Serial numbers too. Little difficult for a novice like me.

I have got thousands of excel workbooks with single sheet in sub-folders in a folder and I want to copy relevant data to another workbook with VBA. Excel sheet contains at A14 "From:"  one or multiple Serial Numbers as parent and their multiple children serial numbers, for example in  in A16 1234345 , so that serial nos can be traced which they are made from...like tracing from from one parents to many children or from many parents to consolidated one. The data is in not-so-organised excel forms.

```
From:         Or From
Serial No        Serial No  
12365            521466
                 541852
To:              752142
Serial No     
12435             To:
34562            Serial No
23645            548215
```

should be:

```
1 File1  From: 12365 To: 12435 34562 23645
2 File   From: 12435 34562 23645 To: 548215
```

As some times, Parents are many and child is single or few, i put no 1 at A1 and increase by 1 for each rows written in Parent or child columns to derive last row and not to mix data output. I am trying to put the file name in the destination B Column, and "From:" or parent Serial no or serial numbers in Column C and "To:" Serial No or Serial numbers as child serial nos in Col D. I have created a macro that activates A14, (there is always "Form:") and find text "Serial No" and copy the next cell with actual serial no until "To:" is found in a cell in A:A some where down there for example A30 or A40. After, I find "To:", I use find "Serial No" and copy actual serial no in next cell and paste in Column D

```
 Sub NewTry555()

Dim File As Variant
Dim fileList As Collection
Dim RootFolder As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim findcell As Range

Set fileList = New Collection


RootFolder = "C:\Users\Bota\Desktop\TestVba\Folder1\"


File = Dir(RootFolder & "*.xl*")

 While File <> ""

'Add File to Collection
    fileList.Add RootFolder & File
    File = Dir
 Wend

Dim FilePath As Variant

Dim objBasis As Workbook
Dim objReport As Workbook

Set objBasis = ThisWorkbook

 For Each FilePath In fileList

Set objReport = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set sh1 = wbk.Sheets(1)

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

With sh1

End With

Set wbk2 = ThisWorkbook

Set sh2 = wbk2.Sheets("Sorter")

Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim Filename As String
Filename = Dir(FilePath)

sh2.Activate

With sh2
 lastrow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastrow1).Offset(1).Formula = 1
 ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lastrow1).Formula = Filename
End With

 Dim LastRangeSearch As Range
sh1.Activate
With ActiveSheet
Cells.Select
Selection.UnMerge

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A12").Activate
For i = 2 To lastrow
 Set rng = sh1.Range("A14" & i)
 Set LastRangeSearch = sh1.Range("A" & i).Find(What:="To:", 
After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, 
SearchFormat:=False)

 Next
 sh1.Range("A14").Activate
 rollno = "*Serial No*"
 Do Until LastRangeSearch
 findcell = rng.Find(What:=rollno, After:=ActiveCell, 
 LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
True, SearchFormat:=False)


For Each findcell In rng

If Not findcell Is Nothing Then
findcell.Offset(1).Copy
sh2.Range("A" & lastrow1).Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

Next
Loop

End With

sh1.Activate
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 LastRangeSearch.Activate

 Do Until sh1.UsedRange("A" & lastrow)

findcell = rng.Find(What:=rollno, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, 
MatchCase:= True, SearchFormat:=False)


For Each findcell In rng

If Not findcell Is Nothing Then
findcell.Offset(1).Copy
sh2.Range("A" & lastrow1).Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If


Next
Loop


wbk.Close savechanges:=False

Next FilePath

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be multiple issues with the code. But what I understand from your requirement that basically you are trying to copying A14 to maximum up to around A40, skipping the text 'Serial No' & empty cells and transposing them in to worksheet("sorter") along with filename. I could not feel any great importance to use of find method.

If that is the case you may try the below simplified brute force code (Since you claim only cells A14 to A40 contain significant data). However for better understanding of the problems may go through some good examples of Find Method and its parameters.Also try to avoid activate etc and take care of Loops with clear view of what you and to achieve.

```
Sub NewTry555()
Dim File As String
Dim RootFolder As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long, Rw As Long, OfSt As Long
Dim FileNum As Long, Txt As String

RootFolder = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder1\"
Set wbk2 = ThisWorkbook
Set sh2 = wbk2.Sheets("Sorter")
lastrow1 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


File = Dir(RootFolder & "*.xl*")
FileNum = 0

    While File <> ""
    FileNum = FileNum + 1
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(RootFolder & File)
    Set Sh = wbk.Sheets(1)
    Sh.Cells.UnMerge
    LastRow = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    lastrow1 = lastrow1 + 1
    sh2.Range("A" & lastrow1).Offset(1).Value = FileNum
    sh2.Range("B" & lastrow1).Value = File
    OfSt = 0
        For Rw = 14 To LastRow
        Txt = Sh.Cells(Rw, 1).Text
            If Len(Txt) > 0 Then
            If InStr(1, Txt, "Serial No") <= 0 Then
            OfSt = OfSt + 1
            sh2.Range("B" & lastrow1).Offset(, OfSt).Value = Txt
            End If
            End If
        Next
    wbk.Close False
    File = Dir
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed AU for very fast response. As a matter of fact, there are more than 100 Serial No under "From:" and only one Serial No under "To:". Similarly, there is only one  Serial No under From and there are more than hundred Serial No under "To:". theretofore,  we have to first find To and catch the source or From numbers up to that point and start catching forward from  To to the end. As the workbooks are unorganized forms, there are blank cells between them. too. Thanks.

Comment: It is a fast code and it helped me to sort my task with different approach. Although, it is silent about using FIND operations, I desperately needed, Tons of thanks. It gave me insight to solve my problem.

Comment: It a pleasure to be useful. In Find method you are searching range A142  onward.with `Set rng = sh1.Range("A14" & i)'. Other issues are also there. May refer [Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and [Link2](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/). It is not necessary  use all the optional parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful links. Wonderful guidance. feeling like somebody gave me a basket of fish and taught how to fish.